# How would I make a scanner anagram?

Tags: java

Essentially I need to create a anagram program to filter out the specific characters I input using a scanner from a dictionary file. Example, if I enter 'Stop' the result would be "tops spot pots" etc

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Anagram1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Anagram1().doIt();
    }

    private void doIt() throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
           String theWord = scanner.next();
            if (theWord.equals("999")) {
                scanner.close();
                break;
            }        
            ISinglyLinkedList<String> anagrams = listAnagrams(theWord);
            anagrams.forEach(System.out::print);
        }
    }
 
    private ISinglyLinkedList<String> listAnagrams(final String theWord) throws 
     IOException {
        Stream<String> dict = Files.lines(Paths.get("Data", "pocket.dic"));
        ISinglyLinkedList<String> theList = dict
                .collect(Util.toSinglyLinkedList())
            //Add a filter and a forEach to print the specific words you wanna print
        
        
        ;
        dict.close();
        return theList;
    }

}
```

So far the program only gives me enter code here every single word in the dictionary. Is there a way to filter out only the words that share the same letter?

Comment: What is a 'scanner anagram'? Title makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that two words are anagrams if after sorting they are the same:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Anagram1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<String>> anagramsMap = new HashMap<>();
        try (Stream<String> dict = Files.lines(Paths.get("Data", "pocket.dic"))) {
            dict.forEach(w -> anagramsMap.computeIfAbsent(getSortedWord(w), x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(w));
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a word to get its anagrams or 999 to exit: ");
            String word = scanner.next();
            if (word.equals("999")) {
                break;
            }
            List<String> anagrams = anagramsMap.get(getSortedWord(word.toLowerCase()));
            System.out.println(String.join(" ", anagrams));
        }
    }

    public static String getSortedWord(String word) {
        return Stream.of(word.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a word to get its anagrams or 999 to exit: Stop
post pots spot stop tops
Enter a word to get its anagrams or 999 to exit: 999
```

Comment: What about `opts`? Good answer btw, but I would load the dictionary on start up and store anagrams in a map whose key is the sorted characters of the words

Comment: The first `Data/pocket.dic` I found doesn't seem to have that word. I changed it to only read the dictionary once.